# Solve the inequalite by $x$ with parameter $a$ and setting cases for $a$

Tags: inequality

I need help with this inequality that contains parameter $a$ alongside $x$. I've done multiple problems with numbers, but I am stuck at this one and could use some explanation.
This is the inequality:
$$(a^2-1)x+a>1$$
My biggest problem is setting the cases right, I first factor $(a^2-1)$ into $(a-1)$ and $(a+1)$ and subtract $a$ from both sides, so i get this  $(a-1)(a+1)x>1-a$. 
Now i bring my negative sign outside from $a-1$ so that i get on my right side $1-a$ and that gets me  $-x(1-a)(a+1)<1-a$

Here is where it gets tricky for me, i find the zero for $a-1$ at $a<1$ and im then left to solve $-x(a+1)<1$ and by dividing by $a+1$ on both sides i get: 
$-x<\frac{1}{a+1}$ 
or
 $x>-\frac{1}{a+1}$
And thats where i get stuck and cant continue...

Comment: Sorry @Tavish i wrote the wrong title, i just need to solve the inequality, i can't find x in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if $a^2-1$, we are left with the inequality $a>1$. However $a^2-1=0$ implies $a= \pm 1$ and thus for those two $a$'s the inequality is false.

So suppose $a \neq \pm 1$ and we have two distinguish two cases $a^2-1 >0$ and $a^2-1<0$.

Let $a^2-1>0$, i.e. $a<-1 \lor a>1$, then $x>\frac{1-a}{a^2-1}$, i.e. $x>-\frac{1}{a+1}$.

Let $a^2-1<0$, i.e. $-1<a<1$, then dividing by $a^2-1$ we have to reverse the inequality and we have $x< \frac{1-a}{a^2-1}$, i.e. $x<-\frac{1}{a+1}$.

To conclude:

-If $a<-1$ the solutions are given by $x>-\frac{1}{a+1}$;

-If $a=-1$ there are no solutions;

-If $-1<a<1$ the solutions are given by $x<-\frac{1}{a+1}$;

-If $a=1$ there are no solutions;

-If $a>1$ the solutions are given by $x>-\frac{1}{a+1}$;

Comment: Sorry for asking a dumb question, but what is confusing me is why does the sign change at a<-1 and a>-1, how do we even get to -1 and the sign change?

Comment: When you divide by a negative number, you have to reverse the inequality

Comment: i understand that, but when do we divide by -1?

Comment: We never divided by $-1$, we divided by $a^2-1$

Comment: I was asking about a<-1 how do we come to this?

Comment: We have the case $a^2-1>0$ that is equivalent to $a<-1 \lor a>1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107526/discussion-between-theslavsquat-and-user289143).

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(a^2-1)x +a \gt 1$$
$$\implies (a^2-1)x \gt 1-a$$
**Case 1:** $ a^2-1 \gt 0 \Longleftrightarrow \color{red}{a\lt -1 \lor a\gt 1}$

$$x\gt \frac{1-a}{a^2-1} = -\frac{1}{a+1}$$

**Case 2:** $a^2 -1\lt 0 \Longleftrightarrow \color{red}{-1\lt a \lt 1}$

$$x\lt -\frac{1}{a+1}$$

**Case 3:** $\color{red}{a =\pm 1}$

$$(1-1)x \pm 1\gt 1$$
$$\implies \pm 1 \gt 1$$ which is not true. Hence, no solutions in this case.